# Throw an error if a folder is empty

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a script, and I'd like to stop the script if a folder is empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
panosDir = '.src/panos'
if not os.listdir(panosDir):
    raise Exception('Panos directory is empty')
```

The problem I have with this code is that I consider the warning in the terminal a bit too much:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\virtual_tours\.archives\bin\python\makeTiles.py", line 32, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "E:\virtual_tours\.archives\bin\python\makeTiles.py", line 23, in main
    raise Exception('Panos directory is empty')
Exception: Panos directory is empty
```

Is there a better way in Python to stop executing a script and throw a customized message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit('message')` to achieve a cleaner error message.

```
import sys

panosDir = '.src/panos'
if not os.listdir(panosDir):
    sys.exit('Panos directory is empty')
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) for more information. It states the following:

*In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way 
to exit a program when an error occurs.*